# Is there a /users/www-data type directory in RedHat/Fedora?

Tags: security, apache, mod-wsgi, fedora, web2py

I'm trying to setup web2py on my Fedora server, and the instructions, written for Debian, are telling me to install it in the /users/www-data directory.  I realize that Fedora uses a default 'apache' user for running Apache, and Debian uses a 'www-data' user, but there's no corresponding /users/apache directory on my machine...

Here are the instructions
http://web2py.com/book/default/section/11/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't expected to follow the instructions religiously, especially in relation to file system paths. You stick stuff in the file system where appropriate for your system, or simply where you feel like putting them. You could for example stick stuff under /usr/local/www if you really wanted to, you would just need to create the directory and ensure that Apache configuration file system paths related to web2py configuration are changed to match that location instead of what the documentation gave as an example.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be tested but may be useful: http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/scripts/setup-web2py-fedora.sh

Comment: Good resource - basically what I was doing - Thanks